# Can/will AMD modules load in-between in-line script tags?

Tags: javascript, amd, umd

For reasons that aren't relevant to the question, my coworker needs to load a script that uses the [Universal Module Definition](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/) pattern. Our environment usually has an AMD tool loaded, but for more irrelevant reasons, my coworker needs the script to define a global rather than registering a module through AMD. The approach that is currently checked in on their branch is something along the lines of this:

```
<script>
    var backupDefine = define;
    define = null;
</script>
<script src="../path/to/some/script/using/UMD.js"></script>
<script>
    define = backupDefine;
    backupDefine = null;
</script>
```

My question is: Is this a horrible idea? Is there a guarantee in the way browsers load scripts from script tags that will ensure nothing other than loading the UMD-based script will happen between undefining define and restoring define? We have a very large, very heavily async asset load primarily based around AMD modules, so what I am concerned with is an AMD module attempting to define itself in that intermittent state where define is currently not defined.

Comment: Can you show us the UMD.js code? I don't realize why you can't use UMD along with AMD, since UMD is only a superset of AMD.

Comment: @Buzinas The concern isn't with UMD and AMD together. That works fine. The concern is with my coworker's attempt to trick UMD into bypassing AMD and defining a global.

Comment: But why does he need to do that? That's my question. Why is he trying to change `define` to `null` when adding the `UMD.js` file, and then, defining it back? Couldn't  `UMD.JS` live along with `define`? That doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: @Buzinas it can and does live along with define just fine, if the code that needs the UMD registered module could load it through AMD as a dependency. Any UMD approach will detect define and register a module through it if it is present. The problem is that in this situation, a module registration is not what is desired. The goal is to get the imported javascript file to register a global variable instead. The sole content of my question is to know whether or not this approach of undefining define is 'safe' or not.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem, but that code should work because the execution flow has to finish all of the scripts before any asynchronous callbacks can be executed.

Answer (score 1):

So long as `UMD.js` in no way modifies the scripts in the DOM, those scripts are guaranteed to execute in the order that they're authored in *before* any asynchronous callbacks that may have been queued before the first script executes.

Answer (score 0):

I see this as a bad idea and spec breaking even if the case where `define` is always necessary is rare or even non-existent due to `<script>` load order considering your case.  In an `AMD` environment, `define`, `require` and the like should basically be treated as first class keywords since their goal is to help you to remove `globals`.

Realistically, you're treading into undefined behavior as far as I can tell and writing code that is hard to maintain.  You're relying on a tricky case with a spec where you have to undefine something and them immediately redefine it hoping that nothing tried to use it in the mean time.  I'd say that that's "unsafe".

If you really need this to happen, I'd comment and document it heavily to make sure a future developer doesn't misunderstand what you're doing.  However, I would say the better course of action is to rewrite the `UMD.js` file so that you export your global your own way.  Rhetorically, why are you trying to use `UMD` if you don't want it to `UMD` things?

You're writing this module to support `AMD` through `UMD` but then you say that you don't want it to be used by `AMD`.  Rewrite the file to just export to the global and avoid messing with `define` before you accidentally conflict with an additional library that does something tricky with `define`.